# Validation of radios with react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-hook-form

I am trying to validate a group of 'radios' with react-hook-form, and the problem I have is that when I select a 'radio' and press submit, I skip the validation, I do not understand very well why if it is already selected.

```
<Form.Check
 { ...register( 'measure', {
   required: { value:true, message: 'field is required' }
  })
 } 
 disabled={isSubmitting}
 type="radio"
 name="measure"
 label="milliliters"
 value="milliliters"
/>
    
<Form.Check
 { ...register( 'measure', {
   required: { value:true, message: 'field is required' }
  })
 }
 disabled={isSubmitting}
 type="radio"
 name="measure"
 label="unit"
 value="unit"
/>
```